# What is the time complexity of WITH recursive in MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, tree, parent-child

I want to create a parentid/children relation in MYSQL and I searched in stackoverflow an example to create this and I saw this code "Getting all children of a specified node" ([source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7150#7150)):

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS ( 
   SELECT id, 
          name, 
          parent_id,
          1 as level 
   FROM the_table
   WHERE name = 'foo'

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT p.id,
          p.name,
          p.parent_id, 
          t.level + 1
   FROM your_table p
     JOIN tree t ON t.id = p.parent_id
)
SELECT *
FROM tree
```

But I would like to know the time completixy of that operation. I suppose that it is O((n+m)*log(n)) or bigger.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8+?  That is the only version that support recursive CTEs.

Comment: What are *n* and *m* in your analysis?